# How to Export Liquid Animation to the Lumion with full Animation?

Tags: animation

First I tried export it with bakes animation and import it to lumion. It's not working.

Then I converted particle system animation to the mesh animation using the script in below article ()

Still its not working after export...

Note : Limion only identifies simple Move, Scale, Rotate animations...So i have to find a way how to export liquid animation from blender according to that requirement of the lumion.

Comment: Lumion cannot import vertex animations or anything that manipulates the geometry of an object. https://support.lumion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003455154-How-do-you-import-animated-objects-in-Lumion-

Comment: Yeah..I know..I read that article before...I want to figure out a way to convert complex animation to simple mesh animation and import it to lumion. Anyways, Thanks for the reply dude.